# Why is the Jobs API returning a "Does Not Exist" error? #linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

When trying to build an integration to pull from job application information into our ATS, we keep getting the error below. But we also get this error with any V2 API we tr yand integrate with.

What needs to be done for this to work?

[image: example]

Comment: So you are passing some cookies and other stuff .. perhaps we need to see what you are doing because its likely not passing the correct values, that or it just needs a method POST instead of GET without parameters to get the information.